# count number of partitions of a set with n elements into k subsets

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinatorics

This program is for count number of partitions of a set with n elements into k subsets I am confusing here `return k*countP(n-1, k) + countP(n-1, k-1);` 
can some one explain what is happening here?
why we are multiplying with k?

NOTE->I know this is not the best way to calculate number of partitions that would be DP

```
// A C++ program to count number of partitions 
// of a set with n elements into k subsets 
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

// Returns count of different partitions of n 
// elements in k subsets 
int countP(int n, int k) 
{ 
    // Base cases 
    if (n == 0 || k == 0 || k > n) 
        return 0; 
    if (k == 1 || k == n) 
        return 1; 

    // S(n+1, k) = k*S(n, k) + S(n, k-1) 
    return k*countP(n-1, k) + countP(n-1, k-1); 
} 

// Driver program 
int main() 
{ 
    cout << countP(3, 2); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Each `countP` call implicitly considers a single element in the set, lets call it **A**.

The `countP(n-1, k-1)` term comes from the case where **A** is in a set by itself. In this case, we just have to count how many ways there are to partition all the other elements (N-1) into (K-1) subsets, since **A** takes up one subset by itself.

The `k*countP(n-1, k)` term, then, comes from the case where **A** is *not* in a set by itself. So we figure out the number of ways of partitioning all the other (N-1) values into K subsets, and multiply by K because there are K possible subsets we could add **A** to.

For example, consider the set `[A,B,C,D]`, with `K=2`.

The first case, `countP(n-1, k-1)`, describes the following situation:

```
{A, BCD}
```

The second case, `k*countP(n-1, k)`, describes the following cases:

```
2*({BC,D}, {BD,C}, {B,CD})
```

Or:

```
{ABC,D}, {ABD,C}, {AB,CD}, {BC,AD}, {BD,AC}, {B,ACD}
```

Answer (score 4):

How do we get `countP(n,k)`? Assuming that we have devided previous `n-1` element into a certain number of partions, and now we have the n-th element, and we try to make `k` partition.

we have two option for this:

**either**

1. we have devided the previous `n-1` elements into `k` partions(we have `countP(n-1, k)` ways of doing this), and we put this n-th element into one of these partions(we have `k` choices).  So we have `k*countP(n-1, k)`.

**or:**

2. we divide previous `n-1` elements into `k-1` partition(we have  `countP(n-1, k-1);` ways of doing this), and we make the n-th element a single partion to achieve a `k` partition(we only have 1 choice: putting it seperately). So we have  `countP(n-1, k-1);`.

So we sum them up and get the result.

Comment: Great explanation, finally got it :-)

Answer (score 4):

What you mentioned is the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) which enumerates the number of ways to partition a set of n objects into k non-empty subsets and denoted by [image] or [image].

Its recursive relation is:

[image]

for `k > 0` with initial conditions:

[image]

.

Calculating it using dynamic programming is more faster than recursive approach:

```
int secondKindStirlingNumber(int n, int k) {

    int sf[n + 1][n + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        sf[i][i] = 1;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < n + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 1; j < k + 1; j++) {
            sf[i][j] = j * sf[i - 1][j] + sf[i - 1][j - 1];
        }
    }
    return sf[n][k];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set) a partition of a set is a grouping of the set's elements into non-empty subsets, in such a way that every element is included in one and only one of the subsets. So the total number of partitions of an n-element set is the [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) which is calculated like below:
[Bell number formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06vxu.png)
Hence if you want to convert the formula to a recursive function it will be like:
**k*countP(n-1,k) + countP(n-1, k-1);**